# Desplegar server UDP en Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

Estoy empezando tanto con docker como con Cloud Run y quizás estoy perdiéndome algo.

He hecho un server udp, he generado el contenedor y la imagen funciona localmente perfectamente con:

```
docker run gcr.io/miproyecto/udpserver -p 8080:4114/udp
```

Al desplegarlo en cloud run con:

```
gcloud beta run deploy serverudp --image gcr.io/pruebas-iot-186014/udpservergrun -p 8080:4114/udp
```

no funciona. Mi hipótesis es que el healthcheck prueba el puerto 8080 TCP en lugar de UDP, pero no se como cambiar esta configuración.

Mi Dockerfile tiene esta pinta:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4114/udp
CMD python ./app.py
```

Gracias!

Comment: El firewall de google cloud para el puerto 8080 está apagado o qué reglas tiene?

Comment: EL firewall no lo he tocado, entiendo que el firewall influiría si no consiguiera llegar al server, el problema llega antes, porque no llega a desplegarse ...

Comment: La imagen gcr.io/pruebas-iot-186014/udpservergrun fue un commit que hiciste de gcr.io/miproyecto/udpserver?

Comment: Editado, lo quise poner generico, y se me olvido cambiar el nombre :).

Comment: El contenedor se despliega si quitas la parte final del comando? es decir: gcloud beta run deploy serverudp --image gcr.io/miproyecto/udpserver  -p 8080:4114

Comment: Como comenta @PakLeiChong quitandole /udp ya te debería funcionar tcp. Prueba a hacer un nmap a tu contendor, y asi verificas que el puerto 8080 esta abierto

Comment: Es cierto! no me di cuenta de en hacer esa prueba

Comment: Luis, funciona ahora?

Comment: @PakLeiChong, me temo que no ... no he podido dedicarle más tiempo... En cuanto pueda darle otra vuelta actualizo. Gracias por el interés!

Comment: Según parece la hipótesis que tenía era correcta y el HealthCheck testeaba el TCP y no el UDP. El servicio CloudRun hoy en dia sólo puede desplegar servicios TCP. Gracias a todos!